# Python: conditional splitting in column based on presence of a specific character

Tags: python

I have developed a procedure that reads a .csv file in and uploads it to a database table. Before uploading to database, I am converting everything except datetime to a string. Below is the snippet of the source data (only 3 columns are given)

```
ID     Mat_Code    date
100    300.0      20.11.2019
101    400        30.01.2020
```

I want to remove the decimal point in `Mat_Code` and insert `df` into the database.

I tried this:

```
for c,d in zip(df.columns,df.dtypes):
   if 'float' in str[d]:
      df[c] = df[c].astype(str).apply(lambda x : x[:-2])
```

But, this code is producing the following `df`

```
     ID     Mat_Code    date
    100     300        20.11.2019
    101     4          30.01.2020   <----Note that the Mat_code has been changed!!
```

I want to develop a function that would check each `Mat_Code` field row wise for `.` and then perform a `rstrip` or similar operation.

I am not in favor of `regex` unless it is needed.

Comment: Can't you just do a `astype(int)` ? Or is there any specific condition to that?

Answer (score 0):

one way to replace the strings is by using regex.

```py
df['col2'].astype(str).apply(lambda x:re.findall('.*(?=\.)',x)[0])
```

or else

```py
df['col2'].astype(str).apply(lambda x:re.findall('(.*)\.',x)[0])
```

Here is an example,

```
In [16]: df
Out[16]: 
   col11  col2
0      1   1.0
1     23   2.9
2      4   3.4
3      5   4.0

In [17]: df['col2'].astype(str).apply(lambda x:re.findall('.*(?=\.)',x)[0])
Out[17]: 
0    1
1    2
2    3
3    4
```

Although simply `df['col2'].astype(int)` would also give you the same output.

Comment: Last line is good  ... hopefully that column does not have a code that needs '0' prefix, e.g. '0031' or something like that.

Comment: @Anurag :Thanks. `df['col2'].astype(int)` would not help as there might be a `0` prefix.

Answer (score 0):

Would this work?

```py
if '.' in df['col2'].astype(str): # or some kind of check here
    df['col2'].astype(str).apply(lambda x:x[:x.index('.')],x)
```

This will work I think. The check would be necessary as if '.' is not in string then the slice will throw an exception.